# Setting enum value at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, enums, runtime

Is there any way that I can change `enum` values at run-time?

e.g I have following type

```
enum MyType
{
   TypeOne, //=5 at runtime 
   TypeTwo  //=3 at runtime
}
```

I want at runtime set 5 to `TypeOne` and 3 to `TypeTwo`.

Comment: This isn't possible.

Comment: Why would you even want this?

Comment: +1 I don't understand the down-voters. Don't down-vote the question because the answer is 'no' up-vote the answer that is 'no' instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just refer to MSDN help [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx)

- An enumeration type (also named an enumeration or an enum) provides an efficient way to define a set of named integral constants that may be assigned to a variable.

Also [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx)

In the Robust Programming Section - Just as with any constant, all references to the individual values of an enum are converted to numeric literals at **compile time**.

So you need to realign your idea of `Enum` and use it accordingly.

To answer your question - No it is not possible.

Answer (score 11):

As others have pointed out, the answer is no.

You could however probably refactor your code to use a class instead:

```
public sealed class MyType
{
   public int TypeOne { get; set; }
   public int TypeTwo { get; set; }
}

...

var myType = new MyType { TypeOne  = 5, TypeTwo = 3 };
```

or variations on that theme.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are compiled as constant static fields, their values are compiled into you assembly, so no, it's not possible to change them. (Their constant values may even be compiled into places where you reference them.)

Eg take this enum:

```
enum foo
{
    Value = 3
}
```

Then you can get the field and its information like this:

```
var field = typeof(foo).GetField("Value", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(null));
Console.WriteLine(field.Attributes);
```

Comment: Incorrect, they are compiled as constants, not static fields.

Comment: @DavidG I added sample code. They work exactly like fields. Constants are implemented as fields as well.