# Set property of type enum at runtime

Tags: c#, enums, runtime

I have a class looking like this:

```
public class Car
{
   public enum Values
   {
      Brand 1,
      Brand 2,
      Brand 3
   }
   public Values _value {get; set;}
}
```

In my main program I read a text file, that gives certain class names looking like this:

```
Car(Brand 2)
Dog(Breed 1)
House(Builder 4)
Car(Brand 3)
...
```

In a first step I create all the entities listed in the text file:

```
var objType = "Namespace.Car"; 
var handle = Activator.CreateInstance("AssemblyName", objType);
var childObject = handle.Unwrap();
```

In the second step I now want to write the value given in the brackets to the property. To do that, I look for the respective property:

```
PropertyInfo childProperty = childObject.GetType().GetProperty("_value");
```

Then check, if the property is of type enum:

```
if (childProperty.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
{
   //now set property value
```

I tried certain things, for example, using SetValue(), but that does not work for enumerations. Is there any way I can do this at runtime?

I looked at the following and people said it would not work, but I think this is not my exact situation: [Setting enum value at runtime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827461/setting-enum-value-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Your question isn't making much sense. You set a property value via reflection the same way for properties whose type is an `enum` type as for any other type. So without a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, there's no way to explain what you did wrong. Plus, the `enum` you've shown above isn't legal C# code, and it's not clear at all how you are parsing the input file. Please fix your question so that it makes more sense.

Comment: I am afraid that is not so. Any other value I can set simply using the `SetValue()` command. Further, the enum I have shown is legal C-Sharp code. It's exactly how I have implemented it and it works fine. Why would it matter, how I parse my input file to get an answer.

Comment: _"I am afraid that is not so"_ -- it absolutely is so. _"the enum I have shown is legal C-Sharp code"_ -- maybe. I've never heard of _"C-Sharp"_ so maybe that's some other language where the syntax you show is valid. But it's not valid in C#.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language) FYI

Comment: That's a URL, not the name of a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the question you mentioned above :

All references to the individual values of an `enum` are converted to numeric literals at **compile time**  therefore it is not possible to do this at runtime

However you might want to use **classes instead of enum**, something like this :

```
public class Car
{
   //public enum Values
   //{
   //   Brand 1,
   //   Brand 2,
   //   Brand 3
   //}

   public Brand  _myBrand {get;set;}
   public Values _value {get; set;}
}

public sealed class Brand
{
   public int BrandOne { get; set; }
   public int BrandTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Use `Brand class` instead of `enum`, Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately changing away from enum to a class would really mess up the rest of my code that is somewhat more complex. I will have to look into that and see if it's practicable.