# How to generate compile time enum values with a macro function in c#?

Tags: c#, enums, macros

I want to generate compile time enum values.

As we do in c

```
 #define macfun(x) (128 | ((unsigned int)(x) << 16L)
```

now if want to generate another const vale I simply do

```
 #define JISCHAR    macfun(3)
```

I'm making a C# wrapper of third-party library and It has defined many different types of constants.

Can I actually generate enum at compile time in C#?

what are the other ways to compute the constant and assign to a variable?

Comment: AFAIK there are no Macros in C# that work anything like those in C. But if you are already creating enums in C#, can't you just assign the values from the wrapped C code?

Comment: There are more than 50 values in one option.  and 8 different options. that's why I was looking for a better way to do it

Comment: Could you use const/readonly fields & use a private function to initialise them (possibly make them all static)

Comment: yes I could 

Let say static const class for option one and one static method to assign the readonly property it's a constant value.  

have I understood it correctly?

Comment: That is the sort of thing I was thinking of - it does mean that you cant assign values to enums like that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [@PaulF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3070060/paulf) and similar answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828917/7708168).

one possible solution could be:

```
     public sealed class UnixDBCSPages
     {
        public static readonly uint JIS           = MakeUnixDBCS(Convert.ToUInt32(0x0C));
        public static readonly uint EUCJP         = MakeUnixDBCS(Convert.ToUInt32(0x0D));
        public static readonly uint CNS11643_1    = MakeUnixDBCS(3);
        public static readonly uint EUC_CNS_1     = MakeUnixDBCS(7) ;                             
        public static readonly uint CNS11643_2    = MakeUnixDBCS(4) ;
        public static readonly uint EUC_CNS_2     = MakeUnixDBCS(8);                             
        public static readonly uint KSC1987       = MakeUnixDBCS(6);
        public static readonly uint GB2312        = MakeUnixDBCS(5);


        private static uint MakeUnixDBCS(uint wCodePage)
        {
            uint wUnixUnmask = Convert.ToUInt32(Flags.UnixUnmask);                
            return (wUnixUnmask | wCodePage) << 16;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can run commands before and after building. Then you can generate/edit this enum with an other program. You basically can edit whole files.

EDIT:
You find this option under Project Properties and then Build Events