# Unity - get all fonts in Resources and their font weights in an enum?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, fonts

Ive seen https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Font.GetOSInstalledFontNames.html however I want to know what would be the most efficient method of

1. Getting all available fonts in Resources folder into enum called `FontFamily`
2. Setting/accessing available font weight for each font into enum called `FontWeight`

Like an Adobe program would.

I can get individual font FILES from Resources with `(Font)Resources.Load("Inter-Black-slnt=0");` however I want to display just `Inter` for all the Inter font files, just `Arial` for all Arial, etc in my enum `FontFamily`.

I then need to see which weights were provided for each font in `FontFamily` and update the `FontWeight` enum accordingly. I.e. if I have Arial-Bold, Arial-Regular, and Arial-Light, `FontFamily` would contain Bold, Regular, Light.

The only way I can think to do this is run a for loop splitting the names of all font files I find, but I want to know whether there's a more efficient/performant way to do this. How can I populate these font enums?

Comment: Could you in general explain a bit what you mean by `enum FontWeight` or `enum FontFamily` ... if you mean an actual [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.enum) then it is precompiled and you don't get your values in there anyway ...

Comment: @derHugo you cant change/populate enums at runtime?

Comment: You *can* maybe in an editor script and then let the entire code recompile .. but it's definitely not trivial .. on runtime so after a compilation, [no you can not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827461/setting-enum-value-at-runtime-in-c-sharp#:~:text=Enums%20are%20compiled%20as%20constant,places%20where%20you%20reference%20them.). an enum is basically kind of a precompiled constant map between keywords and values .. on compile time the enum occurrences are replaced with the numeric literal of the value ...so it is a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve